# what is the work of roslyn csc.exe and what is the roslyn?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, roslyn

**why it throw the error "Could not find a part of the path ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe" ?**

One working project failed to compile after I made a fresh checkout. The same commit that before worked without a problem now got me this compiler error:

`"Could not find a part of the path ... bin\roslyn\csc.exe" ?`

My Actual question is What is roslyn csc.exe and whats the work of roslyn csc.exe?

Comment: It's the C# compiler.

Comment: What kind of project is this? In the .NET 4 / VS 2017 era you had the Microsoft.CompilerServices packages which shipped a newer compiler than what VS could support, giving fancy C# features. You _probably_ just need to restore your NuGet packages to get this running. Then upgrade your project and IDE to get more fancy new stuff.